# Querying Android Content Provider

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider

I am trying to query my `Content Provider` for this data

```
 scheduledTime='1457093280', user='null', isCompleted='false', id='18'
 scheduledTime='1457266080', user='null', isCompleted='false', id='19'
 scheduledTime='1457352540', user='null', isCompleted='false', id='20'
 scheduledTime='1459155180', user='null', isCompleted='false', id='6'
 scheduledTime='1456391940', user='null', isCompleted='true', id='2'
 scheduledTime='1456394140', user='null', isCompleted='true', id='1'
 scheduledTime='1456395600', user='null', isCompleted='true', id='3'
 scheduledTime='1456395600', user='null', isCompleted='true', id='4'
 scheduledTime='1456399260', user='null', isCompleted='true', id='5'
 scheduledTime='1456918140', user='null', isCompleted='true', id='14'
 scheduledTime='1456918320', user='null', isCompleted='true', id='15'
 scheduledTime='1456920360', user='null', isCompleted='true', id='16'
 scheduledTime='1456921020', user='null', isCompleted='true', id='21'
```

And this is how I'm querying it.

```
 final Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, "isCompleted ASC, scheduledTime ASC");
```

Which prints out the data above. But, this is what I want to achieve. Sort `isCompleted` in `Ascending` order and then sort by time. Which means `false Completed` would be sorted by the one closest to the resent time and and `true completed` would be sorted by the one closest to the resent time too. More like, `18, 19, 20, 21, 16, 15, 14, 5, 4, 3, 1, 2` `18, 19, 20` looks well sorted, but `21, 16, 15, 14, 5, 4, 3, 1, 2`. More like, sorting false in ASC order and true in DESC. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Does that mean you want to sort ascending for incomplete entries and descending for completed entries?

Comment: That's right. Remember, they all are on the same table

Comment: Are you always able to determine a time that lies somewhere between the last complete and the first incomplete entry? Can you rule out that incomplete and complete entries overlap?

Comment: 1. Yes. I am able to determine a time. 2. Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two possible solutions.

## Solution 1

If you know a pivot time that lies between the complete and incomplete entries you sort by the absolute distance between your pivot time.

Assuming that your pivot time is stored in a `long` variable called `pivotTime` the query would look like so:

```
final Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null,
    String.format("isCompleted ASC, abs(scheduledTime - %d) ASC", pivotTime));
```

#### Explanation

For all entries with a `scheduledTime` that is after `pivotTime` the expression `scheduleTime - pivotTime` will be positive and the absolute value of it will be positive as well. In effect the sorting order is the same as before.

For entries with a `scheduledTime` that is before `pivotTime` the expression `scheduleTime - pivotTime` will become negative. Applying `abs()` will turn them into positive, inverting the sort order.

## Solution 2

Solution #2 is **sort of a hack**, but it also works if the condition that you can find a time between complete or incomplete entries is not met (or if the times may overlap).

The following query should work in that case.

```
final Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null,
    "isCompleted ASC, ((isCompleted == 'false') - 0.5) * scheduledTime ASC");
```

#### Explanation

since `isCompleted == 'false'` is evaluated to `1` for incomplete entries the expression `(isCompleted == 'false') - 0.5` results in `0.5`. So incomplete entries will be sorted by `0.5 * scheduledTime` which equals the original sorting.

For completed entries `isCompleted == 'false'` evaluates to `0` and  `(isCompleted == 'false') - 0.5` result in `-0.5`, effectively reverting the sort order.